# SYSCTRL like role in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I want to set up a workflow, where a third party (still within the org) grants accesses to our database by granting to a role that has the select or update access to the tables. I would also want this third party NOT to have these accesses. I.e. is not able to read or update data.
In my understanding DB2's [SYSCTRL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=authorities-sysctrl) does a similar thing, but i am not sure how to replicate this in Postgres.

Here is what I am thinking on:

1. user@company.com requests read access
2. Third party postgres role grants the read role: e.g. `GRANT reader_role TO "user@company.com";` all while logged in as a role that has no select access to the db/tables.

What is the usual way to achieve this in PostgreSQL? Currently the third party role has to be granted to reader_role `WITH ADMIN OPTION`.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-DESCRIPTION-ROLES):

> Roles having `CREATEROLE` privilege can grant or revoke membership in any role that is not a superuser.

However, it is not very useful, since it can grant the `reader_role` to itself just as easily as it can to any other role.

A `SECURITY DEFINER` function that wraps the `GRANT` statement can be an answer though. As a superuser, create a function like the one below and grant privileges to run it to the specific role, while revoking it from everybody else:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION grant_reader_role (
    to_role TEXT
)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    IF to_role IS NULL OR to_role = '' THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid role';
        RETURN FALSE;
    ELSIF to_role = session_user THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Not allowed';
        RETURN FALSE;
    ELSE
        EXECUTE format('GRANT READER_ROLE TO %s', to_role);
        RETURN TRUE;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
;
REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION grant_reader_role FROM public;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION grant_reader_role TO sysctl;
```

Make sure you read the section about [Writing
SECURITY DEFINER Functions Safely](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY).

The `sysctl` role, and only that role, will be able to run this function and execute the appropriate `GRANT` statement, and only that statement, with the superuser privileges.

Comment: Good answer, but I won't upvote unless you set `search_path` on the function [like you should](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY).

Comment: I included the link to the safety section in the manual for that reason specifically. Not that I care about your upvotes.

Comment: Point about the upvotes taken. It's just that a lot of people copy and paste code, and we shouldn't try to disseminate code with security leaks. It's easy to [launch a privilege escalation attack](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/abusing-security-definer-functions/) against your function as it is.

Comment: Appreciate your answer! I need to digest it and investigate the security implications mentioned above. Thanks again!